# PHP OOP: Iterate over all objects created from a class

Tags: php, oop

I want to create a  `<select>` field from all Gender objects. Is there a way to iterate over all the objects created from the class of **Gender**?

```
class Gender {

    public static $counter = 0;
    public $id;
    public $gender;

    public function __construct($gender){
        Gender::$counter++;
        $this->id = Gender::$counter;
        $this->gender = $gender;
    }

}

// Objects
$gender_male = new Gender('Male');
$gender_female = new Gender('Female');
```

Comment: This what you are doing here is not OOP. Stop abusing global state.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this was the place where I can ask for directions and be given answers. If you're not going to give an answer then stop replying in respect for those who do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand now that it's an extreme overkill to use a class but for the sake of knowing how it's done, here's the new code (based on all your comments):

```
class Gender {

    public static $counter = 0;
    public static $genders = array();

    public function __construct($gender){
        // Here it is
        Gender::$genders[++Gender::$counter] = $gender;
    }

}

// Objects
$gender_male = new Gender('Male');
$gender_female = new Gender('Female');
```

It's a group achievement in its own way but I think I'll switch to arrays instead. :-)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to iterate over all the objects created from the class of Gender?

To a degree, yes, but it's a very bad idea design-wise.

Why not put all the relevant objects you want to query into an array?

```
$genders = array();
$genders["male"] = new Gender('Male');
$genders["female"] = new Gender('Female');
```

you can then walk through each element using

```
foreach ($genders as $gender)
 echo $gender->id;
```

Comment: I'm pushing myself to learn OO PHP so I *forcefully* used a Gender class. :-)

Comment: @enchance hmmm, I'm not sure whether using objects really makes sense in this context then. If your only goal is to build a select menu, I'd say it's definitely overkill - an array of strings should do

Comment: @enchance , just because you use classes does not make it OOP. Ind this case it is more of a bad design decision.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this you could do.

```
class Gender {

    public static $genders = array();
    public $gender;

    public function __construct($gender){
        $this->gender = $gender;
        self::genders[] = $this;
    }

}

// Objects
$gender_male = new Gender('Male');
$gender_female = new Gender('Female');

foreach(Gender::genders as $gender) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Gender {

    public static $counter = 0;
    public $id;
    public $gender;
    private static $instances = array();

    public function __construct($gender){
    Gender::$counter++;
    $this->id = Gender::$counter;
    $this->gender = $gender;
    self::$instances[] = $this;
    }

    public static function getInstances(){
    return self::$instances;
    }


}

new Gender( "male" );
new Gender( "male" );

foreach( Gender::getInstances() as $genderInstance ) {
echo $genderInstance->gender;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
$_genders = array('Male','Female','Alien');
$gender = array();
foreach($_genders as $g)
{
   $gender[$g] = new Gender($g);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a Container-Class would fit perfect for this task.

Take a look to: [SplObjectStorage](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php)